# How to make sense of "let () ="

Tags: ocaml

In OCaml, how to make sense of a definition like:

```
let () = print_endline "hello world"
```

Let-definitions in ocaml should look like `let x = e` but above `()` is not a variable. So what happens there?

I think it would make more sense to write:

```
let _:unit = print_endline "hello world"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for let bindings is "*pattern* = *expression*`. Most often the pattern will be a variable name, a wildcard or a tuple pattern of those, but every kind of pattern is valid (as long as the pattern has the same type as the expression).

The semantics are that the expression will be matched against the pattern and if the match succeeds, the variables bound by the pattern (if any) will be bound during the `let`'s scope. If it fails, there will be an exception.

So for `let () = something`, you have a pattern that binds no variables and can never fail (since an expression of type `unit` can never produce a value other than `()`). So this is indeed functionally equivalent `let _:unit = ...`, just a bit more compact.

Comment: " but every type of pattern of the appropriate type is valid."?

Comment: @zell I changed that sentence to "every kind of pattern is valid (as long as the pattern has the same type as the expression)". Did that address your confusion?

Answer (score 2):

A `let`-definition in OCaml can define many values at the same time. For instance, with

```ml
let (x,y) = 1, 2 in x + y
```

we are defining both `x` and `y` with the same `let`.
This works the same as using patterns to bind part of an argument in a function definition

```ml
let f (x,_,y) = x + y
```

(One may note that we can rewrite the let-definition above to use only this second form as

```
(fun (x,y) -> x + y) (1,2)
```

)

Moreover, this construction works for all patterns. For instance, we can apply it to pick three variables from nested fields of a record

```
type x = { x: int; y: int }
type a = { a: x; b:int; c:x }
let { a={ x; _ } ; b; c = {y; _ } } = { a = {x=0;y=1}; b=2; c={x=3;y=4} }
```

Note that in all illustration above, we were only using product types. The reason here is that exhaustive patterns are bit more exotic for variants, but they are still possible. For instance

```ml
type t = A of int | B of int * int * float
let (A x|B(_,x,_)) = A 0
```

binds `x` to `0`.

Consequently, a definition of the form

```
let () = print_endline "hello world"
```

can be seen as a definition where 0 values are bound by the pattern and as the symmetric of

```
(fun () -> print_endline "hello world")
```

Comment: Further adding to possible binding options: `as`

Comment: Also possibly worth noting when you use `|` as in `(A x | B (_, x, _))` is that the same names must be bound in all possible patterns and they must have the same types.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for pattern matching matches the syntax for constructors.
Typically a type can have multiple constructors:

```
 type colour = Red | Blue | Greed
```

But let's have a unique constructor instead:

```
 type colour = Red
```

Then `Red` is both a constructor and a pattern matching expression for type `colour`. Here I define a function that constantly returns `Red`:

```
let f () = Red
```

And here I can match it too, given that the match is exhaustive:

```
let Red = f()
```

This is not different for the unique constructor of the `unit` type, which is written `()` for reasons.

The example above is a bit artificial but if you attach data to the constructor then it is more useful:

```
type colour = Red of float
```

Then you can create a shade of red as follows:

```
let foreground = Red 0.8
```

And use the pattern matcher in `let`:

```
# let darker (Red v) = Red (v *. 0.9)
val darker : colour -> colour = <fun>
```

For example:

```
# darker foreground;;
- : colour = Red 0.720000000000000084
```